# Getting/comparing difference in matlab/octave arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, octave

I have two arrays A and B and I would like to find the values in the first column in A that are closest to the values in the first column in B and sort them by difference/closeness.

Example: A is 29x2  and B is 14x2

```
A=[0, 2;
408, 642;
492, 66;
1527, 108;
1560, 16;
1755, 182;
1809, 10;
2133, 42;
2235, 444;
2289, 4191;
2334, 86;
2661, 22;
2709, 2;
2787, 2652;
3072, 200;
3081, 110;
3147, 638;
3963, 10;
4080, 2;
4332, 1674;
4462, 14;
5148, 1042;
5649, 8;
5895, 44;
6078, 284;
6315, 2;
6989, 4;
7485, 46;
7623, 3458;
];


B= [0, 2;
165, 2114;
572, 122;
576, 5416;
581, 176;
583, 278;
653, 28;
655, 4;
656, 154;
657, 16;
658, 4188;
665, 3475;
903, 20;
1145, 8;
]
```

The final arrays needs to be sorted by the closest/nearest x values (1st column) in it.
so when the **C array** is generated it would have **[0,0;492,572] etc...**

I included two plots to give a graphic example.  The first plot shows all the data points of A and B represented as stars and circles and the second plot is zoomed in to show the nearest points between the arrays
the final array would have the items that are circled in orange.  ***(Please ignore the y axis in the plot I'm just interested in how close the values are on the x axis)***

How can I create the **C array** using matlab/octave?

[image: Figure 1 full plot]

[image: Figure 2 zoomed in plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the nearest point in A corresponding to each value in B, use `interp1` with the `nearest` mode.

```
AnearB = interp1(A(:,1), A(:,1), B(:,1), 'nearest');
C = [AnearB B(:,1)];
```

Then sort the results by closeness.

```
dist = abs(diff(C'));
[~, order] = sort(dist);
C = C(order,:);
```

Results for your sample data

> ```
> C =
>
>            0           0
>          492         572
>          492         576
>          492         581
>          492         583
>          492         653
>          492         655
>          492         656
>            0         165
>          492         657
>          492         658
>          492         665
>         1527        1145
>          492         903
> ```

Answer (score 2):

**[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** approach -

```
%// Find the minimum absolute diferences and corresponding indices for each
%// element in the first column of B against all other elements in the 
%// first column of A.
[min_val,min_ind] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus,A(:,1),B(:,1)'))) %//'

%// Find the sorted indices for the minimum absolute diferences
[~,sorted_ind] = sort(min_val)

%// Index into A using min_ind to assciate each element in the first
%// column of B against the corresponding closest element in the first
%// column of A.
C = [A(min_ind,1) B(:,1)]

%// Sort rows of C acoording to sorted_indices to have the desired output
C = C(sorted_ind,:)
```

Alternative approach using **[`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/stats/pdist2.html)** [*Pairwise distance between two sets of observations*], would require just one change in the above code -

```
[min_val,min_ind] = min(pdist2(A(:,1),B(:,1)))
```

Comment: Just a note, this approach is `O(M * N)` time and space complexity, while my answer is `O(M * log(N))` time complexity and `O(M)` space, where `M = size(B,1)` and `N = size(A,1)`

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks on that info.  Is that with `pdist2` too? If not, one has to go through the source code to find out the corresponding figures/numbers, right?

Comment: @Divikar: My analysis is pretty simple: there are `M * N` pairwise distances, both of your methods calculate all of them.  My method does `M` nearest-neighbor lookups in a sorted array, each with a cost of `log(N)`.  Sorting the results is `O(M * log(M))` which is cheaper than the first step since `M < N`, so doesn't appear in the final complexity.  Sorting the `A` matrix would be `O(N * log(N))`, but verifying that it is already sorted is only `O(N)`.

Comment: For this size dataset, there's probably very little difference between the methods, since the constant terms are sure to be higher on mine.  But for a dataset with tens of thousands of points, the difference should be very noticable.

Comment: @BenVoigt Your points certainly make sense. Thanks again for bringing up these helpful info!